# Apple: Enterprise Account, but deploy to App Store?

Tags: app-store, ios-provisioning

I have been asked to build an app for a firm that has an enterprise account with Apple. The app has to go to iTunes.

When creating a Distribution Provisioning Profile, I am given the option for "**In House**" or "**Ad Hoc**" There is no "**App Store**" option.

How can this company distribute to the App Store?

See screen shot here:

[image]

Comment: @BahaiResearchI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app in multiple employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to [this Enterprise FAQ page on Apple](https://web.archive.org/web/20110319021105/https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html), you can't distribute on the App Store using an Enterprise account.  The firm will have to also get a "regular" iOS Developer account:

> **I am enrolled in the iOS Developer
>   Enterprise Program. Can I distribute
>   my applications on the App Store?**
>
> The ability to distribute applications
>   on the App Store is available to
>   developers who enroll in the iOS
>   Developer Program as an Individual or
>   a Company. The iOS Developer
>   Enterprise Program only allows you to
>   distribute your applications to
>   employees or members of your
>   organization through Ad Hoc
>   distribution. If your company is
>   enrolled in the Enterprise Program but
>   would also like to distribute your
>   application(s) to customers via the
>   App Store, you will need to enroll in
>   the iOS Developer Program as an
>   Individual or as a Company.

Comment: I've never understood apple's decision on this.

Comment: @courtsimas Don't you know! it's the game of money

Comment: @ShabiTech Ha! I get it from a business perspective... but from a developer's standpoint, it sure overcomplicates things.

Comment: That FAQ page is now gone. Does anyone know if this is still the stance?

Comment: According to the [compare membership](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) page.  "If your organization is looking to create proprietary apps designed and distributed exclusively to your organization's employees, enroll in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program." So yes, this is still the stance.

Comment: Hi if anyone got solution for this? I need help to upload .ipa to App Store. This .ipa file is Custom B2B . I am having enrolled account also.