# How to distribute app publicly to app stroe using enterprise developer program account. (Not to company employees only)

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution

I already have Enterprise developer account ($299/year), where I have distributed my app for my company employees. Now I want to distribute this app to App store for public access.

Is it possible to distribute using same Enterprise Developer Program account? If yes... Please let me know how...?
OR I must need to register for Apple Developer Program ($99/year)?

Please discuss...

Comment: Ask Apple support.  This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to enroll separately in the Apple Developer Program.

Look at Apple's website here https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll

> "If you intend to distribute apps outside of your organization through the App Store, enroll in the Apple Developer Program."

Also

> "If you're already enrolled in the Apple Developer Program for distributing apps on the App Store, or have an iTunes Connect account for distributing another media type (music, TV, movies, or books), you will need to use a different Apple ID [for your Enterprise account]."

This was also addressed in this Stack Overflow question: [Apple: Enterprise Account, but deploy to App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965171/apple-enterprise-account-but-deploy-to-app-store)