# Limits of ios enterprise account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am with ios enterprise account (299$)
As per Apple enterprise account it's shows 100 iPhones allowed.
So no chance for more than 100 iPhones? or i am understanding wrong?

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: You can read more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745946/is-there-any-limitation-to-distribution-of-apps-in-ios-enterprise-program

Comment: @iPatel if no limitation then why https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/ show 100 iPhones ?

Comment: Yes that confusion, As per my opinion you should talk with apple support center or do mail, they will told you right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's an enterprise account, distribution builds will install on any iOS device.

The limitation you're seeing is for development devices. Enterprise distribution builds install on any supported device without registering/provisioning, unlike builds from the $99 program (outside of TestFlight). So, with an Enterprise account, you could release a distribution build to an unlimited number of devices within your company, for example.

You can also create AdHoc builds from your Enterprise account, which will only work with your registered devices, but it's hard to think of a good reason to do that.

Also, Enterprise accounts cannot create TestFlight builds (nor deploy to the App Store). Create a distribution build and OTA install it, use the Configurator, etc. to whatever devices you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add maximum 100 devices of each type(100 iPhones, 100 iPads etc) per year.

Once you added device then if you remove it then also it will be counted for that year.

When you renew your developer account at that time you can reset your devices, I mean can keep existing or removing and adding new ones.

You should refer [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/) and [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/).

Answer (score 1):

The limitation of 100 devices is present, but that is only for test devices. The test devices are supposed to be used when distributing apps using the developer certificate - for testing while still developing the app (ideally that is).

If you are distributing them through an MDM or Testflight, there is no such limitation.

Comment: No, it isn't. You can either use Hockey (or a similar service) or an MDM for distributing apps outside the store.

Answer (score 0):

There is no device limit for in-house distribution of apps.
The best approach for such distribution is over-the-air installation.
You just need to generate a manifest for the same and distribute a link to your manifest through any HTTPS supported website or you can even use Google drive.

Also, the users will have to [manually trust the developer](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev96a12fb84) as it will be OTA installation and not from the app-store.

Answer (score 0):

You can't distribute your apps via App Store.

Here is a screenshot from an entreprise account portal. You don't have the ability to create App store provisionning profiles.

[image: Provisionning profile creation screenshot]

Comment: This post is talking about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965171/apple-enterprise-account-but-deploy-to-app-store